# How to match text in cmsplugin_text table to URL in Django CMS

Tags: database, django, django-cms

We have created a site for a client using Django CMS and are approaching the launch date. There are a number of links to files on their old site. Doing a search of the `cmsplugin_text` table, I find 12 entries that contain the URL. There is no simple mapping to the new file download URL from the old download URL, so I need to find the pages these 12 entries appear on and tell our client so they can edit the page.

But the database is not easy to follow. So how do I go from the value of the `cmsplugin_ptr_id` column of the `cmsplugin_text` column to the URL of the page? I'm fairly sure that the `cmsplugin_ptr_id` is meant to line up with the `id` of the `cms_cmsplugin` table. That table also has `parent_id`, `tree_id` and `placeholder_id`, but I've kind of got lost at this point.

I'm happy to use either the database commands directly, or to use `manage.py shell` to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should have tried a bit harder before answering.

The steps that worked were to look in `cms_page_placeholder` for lines with the `placeholder_id` and look up the corresponding `page_id`. I could then look up the page in the admin at http://mysite.com/en/admin/cms/page/page_id and that page has a "View on site link".

The SQL statement I used was:

```
SELECT cpp.page_id 
    FROM cmsplugin_text AS cpt 
    LEFT JOIN cms_cmsplugin AS ccp ON cpt.cmsplugin_ptr_id = ccp.id 
    LEFT JOIN cms_page_placeholders AS cpp ON ccp.placeholder_id = cpp.placeholder_id  
    WHERE cpt.body like '%userfiles%';
```

Where `userfiles` was part of the path to the files on the old site.